# Error. When i change application to library, getting multiple errors

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl, android-library, ndk-build

I have one project which uses SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) sources. When i run this application, everything works well. However i don't rebuilt shared libs, these libs already exist in jnilibs folder. I mean, i haven't added task `ndkBuild { path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk' }` in `build.gradle` file. But, now i have changed this application to library, and added to another application. When i run application, it gives me these JNI errors.

```
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStaticMethodID received NULL jclass
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to GetStaticMethodID
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]     from void org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeInit()
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] "SDLThread" prio=5 tid=18 Runnable
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12d680b0 self=0xcf627c00
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | sysTid=15000 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xcb1c2970
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | state=R schedstat=( 109480 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | stack=0xcb0c0000-0xcb0c2000 stackSize=1038KB
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #00 pc 002e8367  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+130)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #01 pc 00379111  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+204)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #02 pc 00375847  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+34)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #03 pc 0024d7dd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+720)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #04 pc 0024db4b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+58)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #05 pc 000d5fd3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+42)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #06 pc 000d5673  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckInstance(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, art::ScopedCheck::InstanceKind, _jobject*, bool)+390)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #07 pc 000d4c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::JniValueType)+220)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #08 pc 000d44fd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*)+596)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #09 pc 000d75b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetMethodIDInternal(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*, bool)+464)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #10 pc 000cad5d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetStaticMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+20)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #11 pc 000e517d  /data/app/com.javadbadirkhanly.jbaemulator-Am-L9E1dng8yHEzBLULuXw==/lib/arm/libmain.so (SDL_Android_Init+552)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #12 pc 000a358d  /data/app/com.javadbadirkhanly.jbaemulator-Am-L9E1dng8yHEzBLULuXw==/lib/arm/libmain.so (Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit+4)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #13 pc 00405c79  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #14 pc 00401775  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #15 pc 004069eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+226)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #16 pc 000afedf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+174)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #17 pc 00200de7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+226)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #18 pc 001fc369  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+592)
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking your logs

```
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #11 pc 000e517d  /data/app/com.javadbadirkhanly.jbaemulator-Am-L9E1dng8yHEzBLULuXw==/lib/arm/libmain.so (SDL_Android_Init+552)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #12 pc 000a358d  /data/app/com.javadbadirkhanly.jbaemulator-Am-L9E1dng8yHEzBLULuXw==/lib/arm/libmain.so (Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit+4)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #13 pc 00405c79  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
```

Noticed that the `.so` path is `/lib/arm/libmain.so`

> /data/app/com.javadbadirkhanly.jbaemulator-Am-L9E1dng8yHEzBLULuXw==/lib/arm/libmain.so

For the latest NDK, this ABI is no longer supported, you should have the proper ABI `.so` for your corresponding device or emulator architectures, i.e. `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64`. And, your .so paths should become something like

```
/data/app/com.javadbadirkhanly.jbaemulator-Am-L9E1dng8yHEzBLULuXw==/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
```